# gradle - NoClassDefFoundException for osgi bundles

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, pmd

I am not sure if this error is specific to PMD scanning tool. I keep getting NoClassDefFoundException during PMD execution. Here is my project structure.

```
build.gradle
pmd.gradle

bundles/bundle1/src/**.java
bundles/bundle2/src/**.java
bundles/bundle3/src/**.java
.....
bundles/bundle200/src/**.java
```

all the java source files are under 'src' directory.

build.gradle - it doesn't contain much.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        smartbowLibs()
    }
}
```

here is my pmd.gradle - it defines PMD rule and report location.

```
subprojects {
apply plugin: 'pmd'
pmd {
    consoleOutput = true
    toolVersion = "6.21.0"
    reportsDir = file("pmd/reports")
    ruleSets = ["${sbDir}/MyJavaRules.xml"]
    ignoreFailures = true
}
tasks.withType(Pmd) {
    configureForSourceSet = file('../bundles/**/*.class')
}
```

All the files related to 'NoClassDefFoundException' are in other bundles' src directory. I thought PMD scans only the source files. I am not sure why it looks for classes that are not explicitly referenced.

But when I use only PMD command line tool (https://pmd.github.io/) without using gradle, it works fine. It generates report as expected, but I need to integrate it with gradle.

Please provide some hint if I need to change something..

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest PMD version? Just set `toolVersion = "6.27.0"`

Comment: Yes. I tried, but getting the same error. i guess pmdMain tries to compile java source files. For my case, by the time pmdMain runs, all the java source files are compiled and saved under 'bin' directory in each bundle. I run it with -x compileJava, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I am getting this. Error during type resolution of field 'COLUMN_NAME' in class com.example1.Bundle1 due to: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example3.Bundle3

Comment: PMD doesn't compile the code itself, but it uses the compiled classes to perform type resolution. The gradle-pmd-plugin should configure it correctly, see [configureForSourceSet](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/434c8d40bb2776b1513a2e4a3b091f98ff636382/subprojects/code-quality/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/PmdPlugin.java#L134-L135). Would you mind creating a reproduction case and post a issue here? https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues

Comment: I updated the post with 'configureForSourceSet.'. Not sure if it's configured correctly. It isn't still working.